# oracle sql function output syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, function, output

I have so problem with my output 
the portfolio_description is null, but I don't think it is matter 
I don't know what the syntax is 
and pass two input parameters P_Portfolio_number and P_Stock_Code

```
begin 
select Investor_Number,portfolio_description
into V_Investor_Number,V_portfolio_DES
from portfolio 
where P_Portfolio_number=Portfolio_Number;

select First_Name,Last_Name 
into V_firstname,V_Lastname 
from investor 
where Investor_Number=V_Investor_Number;

select Stock_name
into V_stock_name
from stock
where stock_code = P_Stock_Code;

select count(stock_code)
into V_count 
from transaction
where P_Stock_Code = stock_code and 
P_Portfolio_number=Portfolio_Number;

if V_count = 0 then
V_output := V_output || V_firstname||' '|| V_Lastname ||'does not exist ' || V_stock_name;
ELSIF  


that one work with the output
```

somehow the one below does not work

```
begin 
select Investor_Number,portfolio_description
into V_Investor_Number,V_portfolio_DES
from portfolio 
where P_Portfolio_number=Portfolio_Number;

select First_Name,Last_Name 
into V_firstname,V_Lastname 
from investor 
where Investor_Number=V_Investor_Number;

select Stock_name
into V_stock_name
from stock
where stock_code = P_Stock_Code;

select count(stock_code)
into V_count 
from transaction
where P_Stock_Code = stock_code and 
P_Portfolio_number=Portfolio_Number;

if V_count = 0 then
V_output := V_output || V_firstname||' '|| V_Lastname ||'does not exist ' || V_stock_name||'in the '||V_portfolio_DES;
ELSIF
```

when I add the V_portfolio_DES at the end will raise the others exception

Comment: which exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will raise the others exception

Which is, I presume `WHEN OTHERS` you used. That's usually a big mistake. Don't raise it if you don't handle it properly. You'd rather let Oracle display what's going on. With your "exception", you handled nothing but successfully hid the error cause.

Anyway: saying that - when you added `V_PORTFOLIO_DES` to `V_OUTPUT` variable, my lucky guess is that `V_OUTPUT` is declared as a `VARCHAR2`, but is **too small**. For example: if it is

```
declare v_output varchar2(20);
```

and the first piece of code works OK because variable's length is less than `20` characters, but - once you concatenate `v_portfolio_des`, length exceeds `20` and you got the error.

Therefore, enlarge variable's size.